# Is OpenGL Primitive Restart supported by Intel HD 3000 on OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, opengl

The title pretty much covers it. Wondering if anybody knows this. I'm seeing both function pointers (as declared by GLEW) `glPrimitiveRestartIndexNV` and `glPrimitiveRestartIndex` are `NULL`.

Also the list of OpenGL extensions returned by the driver does not contain anything mentioning primitive restart.

Macbook Air Mid-2011 (SB i5 w/ HD3000 Graphics). Lion 10.7.4.

I seem to recall being able to get this working on a SB i3 desktop machine running Windows.

Comment: Am I missing something or did you just answer your own question?

Comment: I might have but my evidence is (ever so slightly) conflicting.

Comment: What is the conflicting part? That it does work under Windows, but not under OSX? In any case you've answered your own question it seems. The extensions are not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this comparison page will help you: [Comparing Intel HD 3000 OSX vs. Windows](http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device?d=Intel%20HD%20Graphics%203000&d=Intel%28R%29%20HD%20Graphics%203000). It shows full list of functions that are supported.

Comment: Very awesome link. I will edit my renderer to use glMultiDrawElements.